# MongoDB queries return no results

Tags: json, mongodb

I'm having a problem with querying a MongoDB dataset (["On Street Crime in Camden"](https://data.gov.uk/dataset/on-street-crime-in-camden) from data.gov.uk)

The database name is Crime_Data_in_Camden and the collection name is Street_Crime_Camden. The query to find all records, `db.Street_Crime_Camden.find()`, works fine but anything else returns nothing at
all. Here is a portion of the metadata:

```
{     
    "id" : 509935, 
    "name" : "Ward Name",
    "dataTypeName" : "text",
    "fieldName" : "ward_name",
    "position" : 13,
    "renderTypeName" : "text",
    "tableColumnId" : 258836,
    "width" : 100,
    "cachedContents" : {
        "largest" : "West Hampstead",
        "non_null" : 79813,
        "null" : 0,
        "top" : [ {
            "item" : "Regent's Park",
            "count" : 20
        }, {
            "item" : "Swiss Cottage",
            "count" : 19
        }, {
            "item" : "Holborn and Covent Garden",
            "count" : 18
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried 3 attempts at a basic query:

1. `db.Street_Crime_Camden.find({"ward_name":"West Hampstead"});`
2. `db.Street_Crime_Camden.find({'meta.ward_name':'West Hampstead'});`
3. `db.Street_Crime_Camden.find({meta:{ward_name:"West Hampstead"} });`

According to any documentation or tutorial that I've seen any of these approaches should be valid. And I know that there are hundreds of rows (or documents) that match those terms, so why are these queries returning nothing? Advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Which documentation would that be? Because I'm pretty sure that no documentation suggests that querying for a non-existent property returns results. There is no such field in your document called `ward_name` or any of the other variants you are trying. There's a property called `fieldName` which has the **value** `"ward_name"`, but if that's what you are thinking then you are really confused.

Comment: I looked at the SQL to MongoDB mapping chart [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-comparison/).

What I was trying to do was relate the SQL approach to mongo. In SQL the query would be SELECT * FROM Street_Crime_Camden WHERE ward_name = 'West Hampstead'. Is it the cached contents that I have to query then?

Comment: @SJLovatt, in short; yes, if you want query for the value ""West Hampstead" then you have to query on `cachedContents` since that's the only attribute in your document which contains the value "West Hampstead". I have provided several examples in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46199748/8200937) along with an explanation of how to create a `find()` call in Mongo and a link to the relevant docs.

Answer (score 1):

The common theme in the three aproaches you tried is some form of `ward_name = West Hampstead` but there is no attribute named `ward_name` in the document you shared with us.

Based on the document you show in your question the only way of addressing an attribute with the value `West Hampstead` is:

```
db.Street_Crime_Camden.find({"cachedContents.largest": "West Hampstead"});
```

For background; you address attributes in your documents by using dot notation so the document you included in your question could be found by any of the following find commands:

- `db.Street_Crime_Camden.find({"name": "Ward Name"});`
- `db.Street_Crime_Camden.find({"position": 13});`
- `db.Street_Crime_Camden.find({"cachedContents.top.item": "Swiss Cottage"});`
- `db.Street_Crime_Camden.find({"cachedContents.top.1.count": 20});`
- ... etc

These examples might help you to understand **how** to form find criteria. The [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) are also useful.

Comment: For reasons that I can't fathom, none of the queries you suggested worked so I tried these. 1)  db.Street_Crime_Camden.find({"id":509935, "name":"Ward Name", "position":13, "cachedContents.top.item":
"Swiss Cottage"}); 

2) db.Street_Crime_Camden.find({"name":"Ward Name", "position":13, "cachedContents.top.item": "Swiss Cottage"}); 

These didn't work either. What could I possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: What does this mean: "none of the queries you suggested worked"? If it means that they failed then it would be useful to update your question with the failure details. If it means that no documents were returned then either (a) there are no documents in your collection or (b) there are no documents in your collection which match the criteria you are supplying. I'd strongly recommend reading [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) ... a little background reading could save you a lot of trial and error.

Comment: Yes, it means they returned no results. As for "either there are no documents in your collection or there are no documents matching the search criteria" - yes that occurred to me too. But there are thousands of documents in my collection and db.Street_Crime_Camden.find(); returns them all. And I know that there are plenty matching that search criteria as I've looked at the dataset. That's the weird thing. That's what led me to post this. It makes no sense.